AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'selectExpr' | PySpark
I have encountered the error mentioned in title for the given code below:
sel = spark_df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") \
        .select(from_json(col('value'), schema).alias('data')).select("data.*")
    print(sel)

    return sel


Note: I am using WSL and VS Code for this project and I am installing libraries when the error exists so I have not setup the proper environment in advance.
Earlier it said that spark-cassandra-connector and spark-sql-kafka .jar files were missing which led to java errors. So I had manually downloaded and pasted those files into jars sub-folder of PySpark folder.
But its still giving AttributeError

looks like spark_df is not properly defined. I would add a import pdb in the import part of the files, then before that line you posted, add a pdb.set_trace() and look at the objects by hand you are using. My guess is, that spark_df is not initialized as it should be. Read up on how to use set_trace() https://realpython.com/python-debugging-pdb.

Could you have done something like spark_df = original_df.createOrReplaceTempView() or spark_df = original_df.show() or something similar? These are pretty common reasons for this error.
